# CoreHtmlToImage (wkhtmltoimage.exe) inserts "Â" character in image when html that is converted to image has space

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .Net Core Web API.
I need to convert html to image.  I am using CoreHtmlToImage nuget package to convert HTML to image.
I am able to successfully convert my html to image with one and only following issue:

It converts the space between html tags in the html to Â character in image that is formed after conversion.

Following is the sample HTML:

```
"<div>test test</div>\n\n<div>      <span style=\"color:#c0392b;\"><span style=\"font-size:20px;\">Template One</span></span></div>\n"
```

Following is the code used to convert html to image:

```
var converter = new HtmlConverter();
var bytes = converter.FromHtmlString(objTemplate.HtmlCreative, 100, ImageFormat.Jpg, 100);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```

Following is the image that is generated from above html:

[image]

Is there any solution to avoid this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Probably your browser uses ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of UTF-8. Does your page contain <meta charset="utf-8">?

Comment: This html is generated from ckEditor 1.2.9 on angular page and calls my .net core web api and passes the html code to API Controller method to generate the image.  However when I use the same payload using swagger and call the api with same payload, it works fine.